# Calculator: Buttons ONLY show up when mouse hovers over them in Test JFrame class

Tags: java, jpanel, jbutton, calculator

I'm rushing, so idc about the duplicate. I'm still trying to learn Java and the terms, until the end of this semester, that is. I used a template. I'm using a background image ("panel"), which complicates everything.

**Basically, the buttons only show up when I hover over them. It has something to do w/ the JPanels, clearly.**

I excluded code that you'd probably ask for so that hopefully, someone helps me this time because my buttons are not like the ones I've seen when looking on other recommended posts.

**Also, can I make the JFrame a fixed size (the size in the Test class code)?**

Code may be redundant, but I'm just trying to make everything work. Keep in mind, I'm NEW to Java.

TEST CLASS:

```
public class TestCalculator {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(TestCalculator.class.getSimpleName());
        ImagePanel panel = new ImagePanel(new ImageIcon("01_Crane_AGweb.jpg").getImage());
        SimpleArithmeticCalculator calc = new SimpleArithmeticCalculator();        
        calc.SetColors(null , Color.white , new Color(72,61,139));
        calc.setVisible(true);
        calc.setOpaque(false);
        panel.setVisible(true);
        panel.setOpaque(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        calc.add(panel);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.add(calc);       
        frame.getContentPane().add(calc);   
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(358,379));
        frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(358,379));
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
class ImagePanel extends JPanel {
    private Image img;
    public ImagePanel(String img) {
    this(new ImageIcon(img).getImage());
}
public ImagePanel(Image img) {
    this.img = img;
    Dimension size = new Dimension(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null));
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(size));
    this.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(size));
    this.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(size));
    this.setSize(new Dimension(size));
    this.setLayout(null);
}
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this.getWidth(),this.getHeight(),this);
}
}
```

MAIN:

```
    public class SimpleArithmeticCalculator extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

         //BUTTONSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS !
         ...
         // jpanels, buttons, font, values, etc

        public SimpleArithmeticCalculator() {

          super();

      //I THINK this is the problem:  

      buttonPanel.setForeground(null);
      textPanel.setForeground(null);
      calcPanel.setForeground(null);

      textPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1,0,0));
      buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0 , 5 , 5 , 5));

      displayText = new JTextField("" , 20);
      displayText.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
      displayText.setFont(font);
      displayText.setEditable(false);

      textPanel.add(displayText);
      buttons = new JButton[NUM_BUTTONS];

      for (int i = 0 ; i < NUM_BUTTONS ; ++i) {

          buttons[i] = new JButton("" + buttonTexts[i]);
          buttons[i].setMnemonic(buttonKeys[i]);
          buttons[i].setFont(font);
          buttons[i].setMinimumSize(new Dimension(50,50));
          buttons[i].setActionCommand("" + buttonTexts[i]);
          buttons[i].addActionListener(this);
          buttonPanel.add(buttons[i]);
      }

      buttons[BTN_POWER].setText("^");
      buttons[BTN_PERCENT].setText("%");

      buttonPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5,5,5,5));
      textPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5,5,5,5));
      calcPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      calcPanel.add(textPanel , BorderLayout.NORTH);
      calcPanel.add(buttonPanel , BorderLayout.CENTER);
      add(calcPanel);

      setMinimumSize(new Dimension(358,379));

      setPreferredSize(new Dimension(359,381));

       for (int i = 0 ; i < NUM_BUTTONS ; ++i) {
           buttons[i].setMaximumSize(buttons[i].getSize());
       }

   }

     public void SetColors(Color bg , Color textbg , Color textcolor) {

       calcPanel.setBackground(bg);
       calcPanel.setVisible(true);
       calcPanel.setOpaque(false);
       buttonPanel.setBackground(bg);
       buttonPanel.setVisible(true);
       buttonPanel.setOpaque(false);
       textPanel.setBackground(bg);
       textPanel.setOpaque(true);
       textPanel.setVisible(true);
       displayText.setBackground(textbg);
       displayText.setForeground(textcolor);

       for (int i = 0 ; i < NUM_BUTTONS ; ++i) { 
            buttons[i].setForeground(textcolor);
       }

     }

     //ACTION PERFORMED STUFF & OPERATIONS, BLAH

     public boolean isOpCharacter(char c) {

          return ((c == buttonTexts[BTN_MULT]) ||
                  (c == buttonTexts[BTN_DIV]) ||
                  (c == buttonTexts[BTN_PLUS]) ||
                  (c == buttonTexts[BTN_MINUS]) ||
                  (c == buttonTexts[BTN_POWER]) ||
                  (c == buttonTexts[BTN_PERCENT]));
     }

     public boolean isNumericCharacter(char c) {

      return ((c == buttonTexts[BTN_ZERO]) ||
        (c == buttonTexts[BTN_ONE]) ||
        (c == buttonTexts[BTN_TWO]) ||
        (c == buttonTexts[BTN_THREE]) ||
        (c == buttonTexts[BTN_FOUR]) ||
        (c == buttonTexts[BTN_FIVE]) ||
        (c == buttonTexts[BTN_SIX]) ||
        (c == buttonTexts[BTN_SEVEN]) ||
        (c == buttonTexts[BTN_EIGHT]) ||
        (c == buttonTexts[BTN_NINE]) ||
        (c == buttonTexts[BTN_DECIMAL]));

     }

     public boolean isNonZeroNumber(char c) {

      return (c == buttonTexts[BTN_ONE] ||
        c == buttonTexts[BTN_TWO] ||
        c == buttonTexts[BTN_THREE] ||
        c == buttonTexts[BTN_FOUR] ||
        c == buttonTexts[BTN_FIVE] ||
        c == buttonTexts[BTN_SIX] ||
        c == buttonTexts[BTN_SEVEN] ||
        c == buttonTexts[BTN_EIGHT] ||
        c == buttonTexts[BTN_NINE]);

     }

        public static void main(String[] args) { }
 }
```

Comment: It's kind of hard for anyone to reproduce your problem, and find out what's happening for you, if you only show us half of your code.  Any chance you can paste in the whole lot?

Comment: I posted the whole thing in another post & someone said it was too much!! Okay, I will...

Comment: You need to post what's relevant... you post 25 lines of `private static final int` declarations... and none of those variables are even used anywhere in this code.  That part can probably be safely left out...  Your problem is button visibility... so find all the bits of your code that would be relevant to that, post them, and leave out everything else.

Comment: The buttons are relevant because that's the problem! They're not showing up! They're not JButton = new JButton(""). Like I said, I used a template, and I basically changed the buttons & made the Test class.

Comment: @nhgrif I disagree with you.  If we are going to help this person find her problem, we should have her WHOLE program.  It seems to me that every time someone posts a question, includes HALF the code, and says "where's the bug?", the bug turns out to be in the half that they DIDN'T post.  Let the people answering the question make the judgement call about what is relevant and what is not.

Comment: `I posted the whole then in another post & someone said it was too much!!` - you have been asked to post a `SSCCE`. That is you are expected to do some basic debugging first to isolate the problem. Since your problem is the buttons. Then you need to create a simple example that only displays buttons. Once you get that working you add more functionality to you code. You should not be writing 200 lines of code before you start testing. Start in small steps and it is easier to find your problem.

Comment: I posted the buttons, but someone said it was too much. David understands. Okay, so, the buttons don't show up unless I hover over them. I'll post just the buttons then, again. It COMPILES, so I tested it. It's just the buttons, which happens to be the longest part of the code.

Comment: @DavidWallace Would you like me to post an entire iOS app source code up here because I'm having trouble with a couple buttons on one view of a 10-view app?  Sometimes people post not enough code... but sometimes we also get far, far, far too much.  And from what I've seen, people who just post their entire program without making ANY logical deductions on what's relevant are the same people who've made no effort to do their own troubleshooting.

Comment: @nhgrif If you wanted my help finding a bug, then yeah, showing me any code that MIGHT be relevant is better than making me gaze into a crystal ball and guess what your code might be.  It's also a bit hard to run a debugger against code that doesn't exist -  and running a debugger is what I intend to do with the code in this question.

Comment: @user3078712 What's NUM_BUTTONS?  I can't find it in your code, and it's stopping me from compiling it.

Comment: Best compromise seems like the should-be relevant code is pasted in and the rest of it made available in a link to pastebin or something.  You should have your error narrowed down before you come to StackOverflow, and you should be able to create an SSCCE.  We don't need hundreds of lines of code.

Comment: @nhgrif It would be wonderful if everyone who asks a question on Stack Overflow already has the error narrowed down and an SSCCE built.  But this person has already said she's new to Java.  Perhaps she just doesn't have your analysis and problem-solving skills yet.  So we can make things hard for her, or we can try to help her.  I tried to help her, but while I was messing around copy/pasting the code and trying to get it to compile (which it doesn't), somebody who is cleverer than I am came up with the correct answer.

Comment: I added the full code now. That's what I was trying to say. The part of the code w/ the 'bug' could've been omitted because I barely understand everything myself. I'm still learning and my professor allows us to use templates. This project is worth like 50% of my grade. Anyways, I'm sorry nhgrif. I'm going to see if what was suggested works now. Thanks.

Comment: By the way, not that it matters or is relevant, but how come the `int` values of your constants don't match how they're named?  One is 0, Two is 1, Zero is 15, etc...

Comment: Wow, my own special part!  Umm, your calculator works fine for me.  I can't reproduce your problem.  I will keep trying.

Comment: Lol. There's a lot of redundant code. Do the buttons automatically show for you? I can't post a picture, but they work, but I just can't see them until I put my mouse over them.

Comment: Yeah, for me it works correctly. They are there as soon as the window is drawn.  They turn blue when I hover over them.

Comment: I think it might be something to do with that image that you're trying to use.  Like it's getting in the way of the buttons or something.  Because I don't have the image file, my buttons are unobstructed.  I will try it out with an image, and see if this idea makes sense.

Comment: Yes, it is the image that was the trouble because when I took it out, I saw the blue behind it. I didn't know if I could put "null" at the time instead of colors and I forgot to change it. Thanks so much!!

Comment: OK, it's definitely the image - I tried putting an image there and I got exactly the behaviour that  you described.  Do you want me to keep working on this, and see if I can work out how to fix it?

Comment: Oh, well done, @camickr.  I was just about to try playing round with something like what you've described.  Now I don't need to bother!

Comment: Sorry David, lol. I really wanted your help because I know how determined you were. Thanks a lot for your help too, all of you.

Comment: @DavidWallace One last question... I don't know how to word it correctly, but I don't want the JFrame to resize. I set the PreferredSize and MinimumSize.

Comment: `frame.setResizable(false);`

Comment: It made the frame bigger. I moved pack(); but it still made it bigger. Idk how to avoid that, but I just wanna quit... @David

Comment: OK, I don't know why that happens.  Another thing you could try is `setMaximumSize` - pass in the same values as you pass to `setMinimumSize`, and that should make the thing not resizable.

Comment: That didn't work either. I'll Google it.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to create an image panel class. You can use a JLabel to display an ImageIcon.

```
    frame.pack(); // this is the problem, invoke after all the components have been added
    calc.add(panel);
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.add(calc);       
    frame.getContentPane().add(calc);   
    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(358,379)); 
    frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(358,379));
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

If I had to make a wild guess I would say the problem is that you are using frame.pack() BEFORE you add all the components to the frame.

The basic code for creating a frame should be:

```
//  Create all the panel and add all the components to the panels

JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.add(..);

//  Create the frame and add all the panels to the frame.

JFrame frame = new JFrame(...);
frame.add( panel ;
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Update:

Another problem could be with the following code:

```
frame.add(panel);
frame.add(calc);
```

By default a frame uses a  BorderLayout. When you add components to the frame they are added to the CENTER by default and the problem is only a single component can be added to the CENTER at one time. It looks like you are trying to have a background image. If this is the case then as I suggested earlier you can use a JLabel for the background. Your code should be something like:

```
JLabel background = new JLabel( new ImageIcon(...) );
background.setLayout( new BorderLayout() );

SimpleArithmeticCalculator calc = new SimpleArithmeticCalculator();  
background.add( calc );

JFrame frame = new JFrame(...);
frame.add( background );
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible( true );
```

Now the calculator will be displayed on top of the background. Or if you still want to use your ImagePanel then the concept is still the same, you add the calculator to the image panel and the image panel to the frame.

Comment: I reordered the panels & frame & it all works, thanks so much for your patience w/ me!! My code was all over the place. Thanks for helping me simplify it!

Comment: I get this error: BorderLayout cannot be resolved to a type. I changed "panel" to "background" & imported java.awt & it compiled, but the image didn't show.

Comment: I have no idea what you are doing. Again my advice is the same as before. Create a simple JFrame that displays a JLabel with an ImageIcon. It should take about 10-15 lines of code. Get the simple example to work. Then when you understand how to do this, you next step it so add your calculator to the background image.

Comment: It works perfectly fine w/ the ImagePanel, but I was honoring your suggestion, so I'm going to stick w/ the ImagePanel.

Answer (score 2):

Here is your problem
You have calc created and shown before the panel and the panel shown before the frame.

```
    calc.setVisible(true); <------------Visible first
    calc.setOpaque(false);
    panel.setVisible(true); <----Second
    panel.setOpaque(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    calc.add(panel);
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.add(calc);       
    frame.getContentPane().add(calc);   
    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(358,379));
    frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(358,379));
    frame.setVisible(true); <---Third
```

Yet the calc goes on the panel and the panel goes on the frame. You have them reversed. Create the frame first. Then create the panel and put the panel inside the frame. then make the calc and put it inside the panel. Then show frame. show panel. show calc. You just have the order wrong. I've done this many times.

Comment: The "calc" and "panel" variables are both instance of a JPanel. Swing components are visible by default (except for top level containers like JFrame, JDialog, JWindow), so those statements don't do anything and are not the cause of the problem.

Comment: OMG, WOW!! THANK YOU SOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO MUCH!! I simplified it and it works!! I greatly appreciate your patience w/ me!